# Проверка формы без потери фокуса

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтоб на изменение формы выполнялось событие. Как этого добиться?

Например, код внизу выполняет функцию только тогда когда форма была изменена и она потеряла фокус, а нужно без потери фокуса:

```
$('#search').change(function(){
  alert("Форма изменена!");
})
```

Я знаю что есть `onkeydown`, `onkeypress`, `onkeyup`, но они срабатывают только когда поле выйдет с фокуса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй абзац - полный бред. "Имя" каждого из трех перечисленных вами событий говорит само за себя:

```
onKeyDown - нажата клавиша, но не отпущена
onKeyUp - клавиша отпущена(после onKeyDown)
onKeyPress - клавиша была нажата и теперь отпущена( комбинация onKeyDown и onKeyUp )
```

Следовательно, каждое из трех данных событий "преследует" разные стороны одной цели - реагирование на нажатие клавиш. Данные события возникают сразу же после того, как пользователь что-либо сделал с клавишей( или клавишами ): нажал, отпустил или же "кликнул".
Т.е фокус здесь не играет никакой роли.

Comment: еще есть paste и input

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего воспользоваться обработчиком события [onInput](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp). В jQuery как-то так:

```
$('#search').on('input', function(){
  alert("Форма изменена!");
});
```